# How to find subscriptionId and ResourceGroup name of a flow

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I am trying to create a flow in **Microsoft flows** , which i did. In my application i need the subscription id and resource group name to be configured by the user for other azure services like functions, Logicapps. But i cant seem to find the subscription id and RG name for flows. When i request the http trigger i can see them in the properties , but where can i get them in the portal.

Here's the screenshot of properties sent from flow on a post call.
[image]

Comment: They're right there in the screenshot....

Comment: @HongOoi yes they are right on the screenshot. If you could read my question i am asking how to obtain it from the portal

Comment: @JoeyCai where to ? Its not under `azure` it goes to seperate page called `flow.microsoft.com`